# Xcode Warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

With Xcode 10 and static framework CocoaPods, I see several warnings like this:

> Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'FirebaseCore')

How can i fix it?

Comment: Sounds like you've not installed Firebase correctly - that could be due to a misconfigured podFile or a number of other issues. I would suggest walking through the getting started guide again and give it another try. You may also want to post your podfile in your question so we can take a look.

Comment: This issue is addressed in CocoaPods 1.6.0.rc1. Details at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/8287

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thank you very much Sir for the info, Sorry I am a beginner, so to solve this issue do I have to install cocoapods 1.6.0.rc1 first ? Or still waiting for the stable version first ?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, as many people have said before - this method does not work.

Comment: @RileyUsagi If 1.6.0.rc1 does not solve the issue, please share a reproducible example at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed:

1. Create temporary info.plist somewhere in the depths of your project and...
2. Go to *Pods -> FirebaseCore (and each others) -> General -> Identity -> Choose info.plist file...* for each module with warnings.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually modify and pods if they are installed correctly. Moreover, without any actual information about how your project is set up in the question itself, this Q&A is useless for future readers.